# Creating a virtual wireless AP along side original one like windows hostednetwork

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, networkmanager

I want to create a wireless AP while keeping my wifi connection on (and probably share my wifi connection with the AP). I can do it in windows machines with wlan hostednetwork or in windows 10 with built in wifi hotspot. My wireless card definitely support virtual miniport. So is there any way to do this on linux?

I've seen some questions and comments on this but either they doesn't answer it or not relevant anymore in kernel 5.

Comment: Do you have a wired internet (to test that your access point works)?

Comment: The capability of the hardware+firmware+driver is exposed in the output of `iw list` after the displayed line `valid interface combinations:`. Is there at least  one line having both the words `managed` and `AP` in it? This will tell if you actually can at all and that you're not wasting time, but of course doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @A.B yes the line is `valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a complete answer. I came across the package `https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot`, and it did everything magically. Also how actually this is accomplished can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/software_access_point#Wireless_client_and_software_AP_with_a_single_Wi-Fi_device). Got there thanks to @A.B.